# Facetting 3 plots from 3 different datasets with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have 3 datasets df1, df2, df3, each containing three columns (csv files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/56qh1l5kchsiof0/datasets.zip?dl=0)

Each dataset represents a staked bar graph of the three columns, like so:

[image: This example shows df3, where the three columns of the dataset df3.csv are stacked one on top of the other] 
*This example shows df3, where the three columns of the dataset df3.csv are stacked one on top of the other*

Here's my r code to produce the above plot:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

df = read.csv(".../df3.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)

df.m = melt(df,c("density"))

c = ggplot(df.m, aes(x = density, y = value/1e+06,fill = variable)) + labs(x = "Density", y = "Cumulated ranks",fill = NULL)
c = c + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + scale_fill_grey(..., start = 0.2, end = 0.8, na.value = "grey50")

c = c + ggtitle('Relative valuation of 75-node resilient networks\naccording to their density')  + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

c
```

I now need to build a facet plot where df1, df2, and df3 (each showing the three columns, staked) would share the same x axis scale, as such:

[image: I'm sorry for the terrible doodle... Also, each subplot should be a stacked bar graph, as on figure 1, not a density plot]
*I'm sorry for the terrible doodle... Also, each subplot should be a stacked bar graph, as on figure 1, not a density plot*

Can I just do something like this:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

df = read.csv(".../df1.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)
df.m = melt(df,c("density"))
a = ggplot(df.m, aes(x = density, y = value/1e+06,fill = variable)) + labs(x = "Density", y = "Cumulated ranks",fill = NULL)
a = a + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + scale_fill_grey(..., start = 0.2, end = 0.8, na.value = "grey50")
a = a + ggtitle('subtitle 1')  + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

df = read.csv(".../df2.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)
df.m = melt(df,c("density"))
b = ggplot(df.m, aes(x = density, y = value/1e+06,fill = variable)) + labs(x = "Density", y = "Cumulated ranks",fill = NULL)
b = b + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + scale_fill_grey(..., start = 0.2, end = 0.8, na.value = "grey50")
b = b + ggtitle('subtitle 2')  + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

df = read.csv(".../df3.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)
df.m = melt(df,c("density"))
c = ggplot(df.m, aes(x = density, y = value/1e+06,fill = variable)) + labs(x = "Density", y = "Cumulated ranks",fill = NULL)
c = c + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + scale_fill_grey(..., start = 0.2, end = 0.8, na.value = "grey50")
c = c + ggtitle('subtitle 3')  + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

all = facet_grid( _???_ )
```

Or need I organize my data differently?

Comment: In the future, it would be better not to replay on others downloading potentially dangerous zipfiles. See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to create self-contained data you can add to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you re-organized your data. You want all your data to be in one data.frame so you would call `ggplot` once.  In order to do this, you will need to stack all your melted data.frames and add a column indicating which file it came from. When i need to read in a bunch of files, I use a helper function called [read.stack()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/11407464) but there are hundreds of different ways you can prepare your data.

Here's what I tried. First, we prepare the data

```
ff<-list.files("~/Downloads/datasets/", full=T);
dd<-read.stack(ff, sep=",", header=T, extra=list(file=basename(ff)))
mm<-melt(dd,c("density","file"))
head(mm)

#   density    file variable value
# 1    0.12 df1.csv     modu    50
# 2    0.12 df1.csv     modu   472
# 3    0.12 df1.csv     modu   145
# 4    0.12 df1.csv     modu    59
# 5    0.12 df1.csv     modu    51
# 6    0.12 df1.csv     modu    86
```

Notice how we just added a column indicating the source of the data which we will later use to specify a facet. Now we plot...

```
ggplot(mm, aes(x=density, y=value/1e6, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + 
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.2, end = 0.8, na.value = "grey50") +
    labs(x = "Density", y = "Cumulated ranks",fill = NULL) + 
    ggtitle('Relative valuation of 75-node resilient networks\naccording to their density') + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold")) + 
    facet_grid( file~.)
```

And the result is

[image]

Comment: Oh, this looks so great, thanks a lot. One extra question if I may: how to, in the extra column added, put custom text instead of the file name. More precisely, I'd need the text "n = 25" instead of df1.csv, "n = 50" instead of df2.csv, and "n = 75" instead of df3.csv?

Comment: The facets use the levels of the factor (ie `levels(mm$file)`). You may change those levels to whatever you like (ie `levels(mm$file) <- c("n=25","n=50","n=75")`). Just make sure you replace them in the proper order.